# Map all elements, preserving vector structures

Tags: clojure

For example, how could I best achieve this transformation:

```
[[[1 2]] [3 4] [[5] 6]] -> [[[2 3]] [4 5] [[6] 7]]
```

Is there an idiomatic way of doing this, with any number of levels?

Answer (score 4):

You could use `clojure.walk` to increment numbers in arbitrarily nested structures:

```
(def data [[[1 2]] [3 4] [[5] 6]])
(clojure.walk/postwalk
 #(if (number? %) (inc %) %)
 data)
=> [[[2 3]] [4 5] [[6] 7]]
```

Comment: Another difference is that `mapv` is "eager" and does not return a lazy sequence.